# 404 error after adding custom domain to deployed reactjs app hosted by github pages

Tags: reactjs, github, deployment, github-pages, package.json

I've created a reactjs app and I deployed it to github pages with the command `npm run deploy` this all works great and I can see my app running when i open it from the
settings>pages in my repo. However, I am trying to add a custom domain and this is causing me trouble. I configured the IPs and everything for the DNS according to gh-pages documentation and the DNS checks all pass when i add the domain name. But when i go to the domain in my browser I get all 404 errors like this: [image]

[image]

Im thinking it could be something wrong with my package.json, I was thinking I need to change the `"homepage"` value to my new domain instead of the `http://<Github-username>.gihub.io/<repoName>/` I set it to when i deployed the app? Ive tried this but it doesnt work to load the page at that url.

So Im wondering if anyone has run into this issue after deploying to gh-pages and then adding a custom domain?

this is my package.json:

```
{
  "homepage": "http://CRJones7.github.io/learned/",
  "name": "learned",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@primer/octicons-react": "^17.9.0",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "bootstrap": "^5.2.3",
    "jquery": "^3.6.1",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.4.4",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "reactstrap": "^9.1.5",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "predeploy": "npm run build",
    "deploy": "gh-pages -d build",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "gh-pages": "^4.0.0"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the solution, I just needed to re-deploy my page with
`npm run deploy`